# Laravel repositories and services pattern -> access relationships

Tags: php, laravel

I need a way to access a model's relationships without breaking the repositories pattern. For example, normally (without this pattern) we just need something like: `$formation->courses()->create($data)`, but I don't know how I can do that with the repositories pattern...
Recently I saw that there are people who just create the "createWithParent()" method in the repository, but I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: Adding the related models to the parent model and updating the parent model would still be allowed in the repository pattern right? Of course this means you need to somehow link the parent model repository with the related models repository as well as fill in any pivots

Comment: All are already related in the parent model! But I'm looking to do this without making the code too massive...

Comment: You are trying to implement the repository pattern from scratch. I think you should expect it to get massive if you want to achieve the same things that you can do with Laravel's implementation of the active record pattern since that is already quite a complex codebase as well.